# IGMP problem(sending report from wrong interface)

Tags: linux, networking, multicast, igmp

We have centos 7 with several inteface(vlan configuration).

```
eno1.900@eno1
eno1.956@eno1
eno1.957@eno1
```

When we joining to multicast with (ip addr add IP dev eno1.956 autojoin) command.
Our system sending report packer from lo interface, but leave packer sending from binding(from command) interface.

```
tcpdump -i lo igmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:19:26.686734 IP x.x.x.x > y.y.y.y: igmp v2 report y.y.y.y
12:19:31.439741 IP x.x.x.x > y.y.y.y: igmp v2 report y.y.y.y

tcpdump -i eno1.956 igmp
12:16:23.310461 IP x.x.x.x > all-routers.mcast.net: igmp leave y.y.y.y
```

Can you tell me what we missing?